# How do you calculate the total damage output?

Tags: torchlight

According to my character sheet, my level 35 destroyer deals 514-1,028 strength damage, 0 ranged damage and 9-17 magic damage. Summing these values gives me:

```
514 + 0 + 9 = 523
1,028 + 0 + 17 = 1,045
```

Gnomeslice's level 24 alchemist, according to his character sheet, deals 2-3 strength damage, 306-612 ranged damage and 287-573 ranged damage. Summing these values gives me:

```
2 + 306 + 287 = 595
3 + 612 + 573 = 1,188
```

Does that mean that my level 35 destroyer deals 523-1,045 damage per second, while Gnome's level 24 alchemist does 595-1,188? or do these damage figures overlap, bringing a total damage per second that's less than the sum of its parts?

Comment: Those numbers in the character sheet seem to indicate raw damage per hit, not DPS.  You can verify this by switching between weapons of similar type and observing the relation between weapon damage and your character sheet damage.

Comment: Unrelated, I'm curious what the alchemist has equipped?  It seems unusual to me to have both strength and ranged damage unless dual wielding.  However, a number as low as 2-3 strength typically means the character is using his bare hands/fists, which is odd because those numbers suggest he has a magical ranged weapon equipped.

Comment: In TL2 those numbers are independent components of damage per hit.  So the sum of the damage would be correct (but not per second.)  However I am not 100% certain that's how it works in TL1.

Answer (score 2):

The [Torchlight Wikia](http://torchlight.wikia.com/wiki/Game_Mechanics) page breaks the damage formulas down as follows:

> `[ ( min dmg + max dmg ) / 2 ] / speed = DPS`
>
> So if you have a sword that does 25 - 35 damage every .56 seconds,
>   this should apply:
>
> ```
> [ ( 25 min dmg + 35 max dmg ) / 2 ] / .56 speed = 53.57
> ```
>
> Elemental damage socket gems (not sure about other types) are tacked
>   on to max damage and go into the calculation as such:
>
> `{ ( min dmg + max dmg) / 2 + gem dmg } / speed = DPS`
>
> So adding a +23 fire damage gem to a sword that does 25 - 35 damage
>   every .56 seconds should look like this:
>
> ```
> { ( ( 25 min dmg + 35 max dmg) / 2 + 23 gem dmg ) } / .56 speed =
>  94.64 rounded to 95 DPS
> ```

*Armis* on the [Runic Games forum](http://forums.runicgames.com/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=44975), created a formula that accounts for other factors that mitigate damage and give more than a raw output of the character under an ideal:

> DPS = (1+bonus_damage) * (1+speed_bonus) * [(1- u * fumble%) * [(1-crit%) * base_dps + crit% * crit_dmg * crit_dps] + u * fumble% *
>   fumble_dmg * base_dps]
>
> The idea is basically that:
>
> - if you fumble, you deal your fumble damage (if it’s an auto-attack,    obviously)
> - if you don’t, you have a chance to crit and deal crit damage (plus    your crit damage bonus)
> - otherwise you deal normal damage
> - whatever happens, it’s all augmented by bonus damage and the    appropriate speed bonuses
>
> But it gets worse, because sometimes base_dps is actually made of
>   different things: physical and elemental damage. In this case, I won’t
>   type out the whole equation but basically you need to split the
>   physical and elemental damage, calculate DPS separately, then add them
>   up again, all because elemental damage is increased by Focus (and some
>   specific bonus sources, like +15% ice damage) while physical isn’t.

The above is accompanied with an exhaustive explanation defining mitigating factors and how they tested to work in the study. Briefly:

> **GEAR**
>
> There are many affixes on gear that can impact the equation above
>   (poetically named “(2)”).
>
> - increases to attack or cast speed add to the speed_bonus variable
> - damage increases, when relevant (and including Strength and Focus, or    Melee/Ranged bonuses), add to the damage_bonus variable
> - affixes modifying crit chance, crit damage, fumble chance and fumble    recovery add to their respective variables
>
> ...what happens with stuff that adds fixed damage?
>
> ...It depends on whether it’s a weapon socketable (or a weapon
>   enchantment) or not. If it is, the added damage value gets added to
>   the base weapon damage per hit. ...if you add a Skull of Vellinque
>   (+199 physical damage) to a weapon that deals 100 damage per hit,
>   you’re essentially tripling the total DPS (give or take). Bear in mind
>   that if you add elemental damage such as from Embers, it gets bonus
>   damage from Strength AND Focus (and all other applicable bonus
>   sources). The flip side is that ... flat-damage skill, your weapon is
>   irrelevant and so is this socketable.
>
> If it’s not a weapon socketable/enchantment...it gets no bonus damage
>   whatsoever. That +173 ice damage necklace basically adds 173 ice
>   damage to your final damage number before fumbles and crits, but
>   that’s it. You could have 2000 Focus and you’d still only get +173 ice
>   damage, even with skills. Note that the bonus damage from Sword and
>   Board works like this too...
>
> Adding to the confusion is how the game calculates it: all elemental
>   damages are actually calculated and applied separately, which means
>   that enemy armor will apply separately to each of them. In addition,
>   when socketing a physical damage gem (or enchant, etc.) in a weapon
>   dealing physical damage, the game will count it separately. In other
>   words, any addition of physical damage applies separately from the
>   weapon's base physical damage.
>
> **WEAPONS**
>
> 1. Skills that are NOT based on weapon DPS do not transmit any active
>      effect (i.e. DoTs, % chance to cast spells, armor debuffs, etc.).
> 2. Skills based on weapon DPS may transmit some, but it depends on the
>      effect and on the skill.
>
> **ATTRIBUTES**
>
> Attributes define a lot of the damage variables. What often happens is
>   you take an attribute, derive the base value of, say, crit chance, and
>   then add to that all the fixed bonuses you have (usually from gear).
>
> - Crit% = Dex * (0.2002 – 0.0002 * Dex), capped at 50.1% at 500 Dex    (Dodge also follows this relationship)
> - Crit_dmg = 50 + Str * 0.4, capped at 450% (technically 449.6%;    basically Str above 999 doesn’t give you anything. Total crit damage
>     from all sources caps at 500% in the Arcane Statistics screen though)
> - Fumble% = 21%, and no amount of stats will change that number, only    gear will improve it.
> - Fumble_dmg = 25 + Dex * (0.3003 – 0.0003 * Dex), capped at 100% at    476 Dex
> - Execute% = 9.8 + Foc * (0.2002 – 0.0002 * Foc), capped at 60% at 500    Focus (technically 498)
> - Block% = Vit * (0.2002 - 0.0002 * Vit), capped at 50.1% at 500 Vit

Through that, *beastmodeengaged* on the Runic Games forum was inspired to create this [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dQQalu-FuV04sO65pSw6wRmhtSiyT3Tcw1iI6i20s2A/edit#gid=0) with the notice it is designed around the Engineer/Emberquake class and can be modified to apply to others as well.