# How to calculate total weapon DPS?

Tags: torchlight

I have a mace with slow attack speed that has 122 DPS (physical damage 41-81). It also has 11 electric, 3 ice and 3 poison damage. What would the actual DPS of the mace be? Is it higher than that of an axe with average attack speed that has 138 DPS (physical damage 51-101)?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade. Sadly this is not a forum, we only deal with questions which have a definitive answer. This means that answers to your question will vary between users, meaning there is no 'correct' answer to accept. You can find out more in the Tour https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: @DavidYell, this doesn't seem to be to be opinion-based: it's asking whether a mace with a 122 DPS rating, 11 electric, 3 ice, and 3 poison damage does more total DPS than an axe with a 138 DPS rating.  This is objectively answerable.

Comment: But then I would phrase the question differently: the real question becomes "does the 122 DPS include or exclude the electric, ice, and poison damage?".

Answer (score 2):

According to [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Torchlight/comments/17b696/quick_question_about_dmg_on_items/) (not a great source I know), the DPS of a weapon should already include any +dmg abilities that are built in. From the question it seems like your mace has those +dmg built in rather than being gem added, so the overall DPS of the Mace would be lower than the Axe assuming the attack is made against a target with no resistances or weaknesses.

If the additional damage is coming from Gems, that has to be calculated sperately according to [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70175/how-do-you-calculate-the-total-damage-output) and its source the Torchlight [Wika](https://torchlight.fandom.com/wiki/Game_Mechanics#DPS_calculation_is_a_bit_wonky.).

> { [( min dmg + max dmg) / 2] + gem dmg } / speed = DPS

Comment: So you're saying that the stuff in blue is included in the DPS? Then why is it blue?